# Trying to fix a navigation bar with a drop down menu to top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a navigation bar to a web app I'm making for a class, and I wanted to use a drop-down menu in it *(too many things to include to put everything straight across)*.

I want the bar to be fixed to the top of the page, but when I put in `position: fixed;`, the drop-down menu stops working. 
Is there any way around this? Am I just putting the `position: fixed;` in the wrong spot, or is conflicting with the drop down content having `position: absolute;` maybe...?

*(I'm very new to web stuff, so if you see anything else I could change/approve, please let me know! Advice very much appreciated)*

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #111;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  </br>
  </br>

  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="/homePageAgent">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">View Pages</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="/agentViewFlights">View Booked Flights</a>
        <a href="/agentTopCustomers">View Top Customers</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li style="float:right"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</head>

</html>
```

Basically, "View Pages" should become a drop down menu when hovered over with the mouse, and it does if I take out the "position:fixed;" line, but... I want the position to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your navigation into a layer. And make this layer with fixed position.

```css
.navbar-top {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  /*position: fixed;*/
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #111;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar-top">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="/homePageAgent">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">View Pages</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="/agentViewFlights">View Booked Flights</a>
          <a href="/agentTopCustomers">View Top Customers</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li style="float:right"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not apply for the `position:fixed` on the `UL`
You can use a div to warp the UL and apply on it the position fixed.
Here is one way to achieve this ([live demo](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=7f6d05e7-9289-42dc-b443-84321e38a6b7)):

```css
.mainheader {
  height: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #333;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  top: 0;
  font-family: Calibri;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #111;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mainheader">
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="active" href="/homePageAgent">Home
                </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">View Pages
                </a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="/agentViewFlights">View Booked Flights
                  </a>
            <a href="/agentTopCustomers">View Top Customers
                  </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li style="float:right">
          <a href="/logout">Logout
                </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete ul{overflow:hidden;}