# dropdown list isn't working when fixing its position

Tags: html

This link contains a code to make HTML dropdown lists.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar

However, if I want to make the bar header and fix its position by modifying the following

```
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

to

```
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

it won't work again. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Show your whole code please.

Comment: Please, paste a minimal riproducible example here for future visitors, links can expire!

Comment: Maybe a similar question with several answers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074466/trying-to-fix-a-navigation-bar-with-a-drop-down-menu-to-top-of-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `overflow: hidden;` from the `.navbar`